# making the transformed layer as normal state in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, transform, calayer

Hi all i am trying to use CATransform3D in my project.i seen some code snippet for transforming a layer  that is shown below.my question is after transforming the layer with below code how to get layer in the normal dimensions which means same as before transforming of the layer

```
 -(IBAction)animateThumbnail{
CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform,30.0f * M_PI / 180.0f , 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

[CATransaction begin]; 
[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0]forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
imageLayer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
[CATransaction commit];
}
```

can any one please post your way of transformation to get my layer should be in the normal state.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `+[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:]` and set the transform to `CATransform3DIdentity`. Or, you could use a [CAPropertyAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAPropertyAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) and set [autoreverses](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CAMediaTiming) to YES.

Comment: jtbandes i tried with your approach but i didnt find the normal layer once transformed it.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: i transformed a layer i given information in my question itself.now i want to take it back means same as before the transformation applied to the same layer is it possible